# How to deploy a Play framework project to Amazon?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, deployment, playframework, war

Is it possible to create a .war of a project running on Play, so that it can be easily deployed on Amazon? Or is it necessary to install play on the server itself where the app will be run?

I would prefer a .war since I want traffic from all sources to be able to run the app, not just on port 9000.

Comment: What does "I would prefer a .war since I want traffic from all sources to be able to run the app, not just on port 9000." mean?  War files and ports are unrelated.

Comment: @JamesWard Sorry, I meant that I wanted anyone coming to the website to be able to access the app, and not just on port 9000. But that's not a problem, I've discovered that running the app via `stage` or `start` will take care of that, so that should be good to go. Now I just want to know how to deply / run on amazon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this for play 1.x, http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/production
and this for 2.x, http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Production

For easier deployment over SSH you may want to look at, https://github.com/nylund/play-deploy/blob/master/documentation/manual/home.textile (disclaimer I wrote the plugin).

Answer (score 1):

You've got quite few concepts mixed there.

The Port the app listens to is 9000 by default but you can change it in application.conf to whatever you want, or even have different ports configured for dev/test/production,... This has nothing to do with war or no war deployment.

Traffic from all sources to be able to run the app, if you mean where the traffic comes from, that's the source port, not the port where your server runs. The only thing I can make sense of there is that you might be thinking about people behind firewalls or proxy's that can typically only access ports 80 or 8080. But as said before, you can listen at whatever port you want.

You might also be referring to port 9000 being firewalled by default in AWS, but again this is something you can set up.

In any case, the answer to the original question is yes, you can create a war and instead of installing Play you can install Tomcat/Jboss/... and deploy it there, but is not related to any of your concerns, so probably just go with Play standalone and save yourself a bunch of problems.